# Single Row Horizontally Scrolling/Swipeable GridView

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, windows-runtime, uwp

I wanted a single-row GridView that can be scrolled horizontally both with mouse and touch swipe. The GridView is to present images through binding so that a single image will be selected from an array of images.

Everything works fine (binding, image selection, etc.) except that the horizontal scroll doesn't work. The XAML code is shown below.

What am I missing?

```
<GridView x:Name="IconGridView"
    Grid.Row="0"
    Margin="8,12"
    DataContext="{x:Bind IconManagerObj}"
    DoubleTapped="{x:Bind IconGridView_DoubleTapped}"
    IsItemClickEnabled="True"
    IsSwipeEnabled="True"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=IconImageInfo}"
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
    SelectionMode="Single"
    Tapped="{x:Bind IconGridView_Tapped}">

    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>

    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Margin="4,8"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            BorderBrush="{ThemeResource SubtleBlueBrush}"
            BorderThickness="1">
               <Image Width="150" Source="{Binding IconImage}Stretch="Uniform"/>
           </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have everything right but the **Orientation** for the ItemsWrapGrid must be **Vertical** in order to have an Horizontal ScrollViewer.

The documentation here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemswrapgrid.aspx explains that:

When the value is Vertical, the grid adds items in columns from top to bottom, then wraps from left to right. Columns of items scroll or pan horizontally.

Answer (score 4):

**Juan Pablo Garcia Coello**'s answer put me on the right track but didn't work without an additional setting. The crucial thing I found out through trial was setting the **Height** for GridView.

- **Height** must be set enough for a single row elements to display **but** not high enough to allow a second row. For image height of 100 I set this arbitrarily to 140 and works great.
- `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode` must be **Disabled**
- `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode` must be **Auto** or **Enabled**
- `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` must be **Auto** or **Enabled**
- The most crucial, as Juan indicated, the **`ItemsWrapGrid Orientation`** must be **Vertical** (sounds counterintuitive but works!)

I have marked Juan's as answered as it provides a complete answer with this one, due to the fact that I couldn't have quickly figured out a complete answer without the Orientation being set Vertical -- a rather counter-intuitive setting if you ask me but now I get it.

Comment: Hmm the height should not be set actually... Here is my take to it. http://depblog.weblogs.us/2015/03/25/show-items-scrolling-horizontally-with-listview-in-winrt/ if you want I can add it as an answer, because I use a stack panel instead of a wrap panel and it works fine!