# UWP GridView Scrollable until clicked

Tags: gridview, uwp, windows-10, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I created this GridView in UWP and it displays what I want, but in order to scroll it, I need to click on it before, and then scroll. And when using the touch interface I need to tap once and then scroll. And also when selecting an item, I need to tap/click twice.

Is there any way to avoid such need to select and then scroll?

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="Title" Margin="0,0,0,20" Style="{ThemeResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}" Grid.Row="0"></TextBlock>
    <GridView x:Name="ReportsGridView" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Reports, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Row="1" 
              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" >
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Report">
                ...
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
</Grid>
```

I already tried setting the focus programatically:

```
ReportsGridView.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
```

Comment: Why are you manipulating the ScrollViewer properties?

Comment: @Jessica To make it scroll horizontally without showing the scroll bar. (See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34476647/single-row-horizontally-scrolling-swipeable-gridview)

Comment: If you don't change anything, does it work as expected?

Comment: @Jessica Yes, but I have to tap once over the GridView before I can select an item or scroll (using the mouse wheel or swiping).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It wasn't anything related to the GridView itself. I had a CommandBar with its IsOpen property set to True.

```
<CommandBar IsOpen="True">
```

So, the first tap/click was needed to close the bar before being able to scroll or select.